# Search multiple specified folders until Dir returns directory that matches current Outlook folder

Tags: vba, outlook, directory, filepath

I have VBA code to match the Outlook folder I'm in with the client folder and open it with Shell.

I used the script for a while, but it stopped working after I made changes.

When I added a MsgBox with the FullPath, it showed the correct file path, and I could copy and paste the way into Windows Explorer successfully.

Some background:

1. Our office organizes client folders by year, client number, and last name (Ex. 2022-1234 Doe).
2. I organize my email inbox by client number, last name, and property address (ex. 1234 Doe ---- 1 Main St.)

The script:

- removes the property address ( ---- 1 Main St.)
- replaces "SR" with "Seller Rep" (if applicable)
- adds the year prefix (1234 Doe --> 2022-1234 Doe) if it isn't already there
- searches for the folder

If that folder doesn't exist, it searches the next year down and the non-Real Estate Transaction Folders.
Then, if it still doesn't exist, it adds a suffix (Commercial, Purchase, Refi, EF, CTD, and a combination of the three) and searches all years down.
If no folder can be matched, it gives me a MsgBox with the ending FullPath.

```
Public Sub OpenMeUp()

'Get the Name of the folder we're in
Dim myExplorer As Outlook.Explorer
Dim myFolder As Outlook.folder
Set myExplorer = Application.ActiveExplorer
Set myFolder = myExplorer.CurrentFolder

Dim fileNumber As String

'Prepare the searchable path
Dim PrePath As String
Dim FirstFour As String
Dim FullPath As String
Dim ClientName As String
Dim ClientNameClean As String
Dim ClientNameCleaner As String
Dim FileNumberDirty As String
Dim StrFileExists As String
Dim pos As Variant
Dim pos2 As Variant
Dim fileNumberClient As String

'Sets up folders array
Dim FLD(7) As Variant

FLD(1) = "R:"
FLD(2) = "W:"
FLD(3) = "O:"
FLD(4) = "R:\Archive\2019 Closings"
FLD(5) = "R:\Archive\2018 Closings"
FLD(6) = "C:\Users\Meaghan Denelle\Dropbox\Denelle Law\Clients\2022 Deed Transfers"
FLD(7) = "C:\Users\Meaghan Denelle\Dropbox\Denelle Law\Clients"

Dim SFX(11) As Variant

SFX(1) = " (EF)"
SFX(2) = " Purchase"
SFX(3) = " Refi"
SFX(4) = " Commercial"
SFX(5) = " (CTD)"
SFX(6) = SFX(1) & SFX(0)
SFX(7) = SFX(3) & SFX(0)
SFX(8) = SFX(4) & SFX(0)
SFX(9) = SFX(3) & SFX(0)
SFX(10) = SFX(4) & SFX(1) & SFX(0)
SFX(11) = SFX(3) & SFX(5)

'Define my important variables
pos = InStr(myFolder.Name, "-")
pos2 = InStr(myFolder.Name, " ")
If (pos > 0) Then ClientName = Left(myFolder.Name, InStr(myFolder.Name, "-") - 1) Else ClientName = Right(myFolder.Name, Len(myFolder.Name) - pos2)
ClientNameClean = Replace(ClientName, " SR ", " Seller Rep")
FileNumberDirty = "\" & myFolder.Name
fileNumberClient = "\" & ClientName

GoTo SortTheFiles

'This sorts the files based on their year prefix if they have one.
SortTheFiles:
FirstOne = Left(ClientNameClean, 1)
FirstFour = Left(ClientNameClean, 4)
Debug.Print FirstFour

If FirstOne = "1" Then
GoTo CheckPrefix
Else
GoTo Check22

Check22:
If FirstFour = "2022" Then
FullPath = FLD(1) & "\" & ClientNameClean
GoTo Check22Open
Else
GoTo CheckPrefix
End If

Check22Open:
StrFileExists = Dir(FullPath, vbDirectory)
If StrFileExists = "" Then
GoTo Check22Closed
Else
GoTo Oui
End If

Check22Closed:
FullPath = FLD(2) & "\" & ClientNameClean
StrFileExists = Dir(FullPath, vbDirectory)
If StrFileExists = "" Then
GoTo CheckPrefix
Else
GoTo Oui
End If

Check21:
If FirstFour = "\2021" Then
FullPath = FLD(2) & ClientNameClean
StrFileExists = Dir(FullPath, vbDirectory)
If StrFileExists = "" Then
GoTo Check20
Else: GoTo Oui
End If
Else: GoTo Check20
End If

Check20:
If FirstFour = "\2020" Then
FullPath = FLD(3) & fileNumber
StrFileExists = Dir(FullPath, vbDirectory)
If StrFileExists = "" Then
GoTo Check19
Else: GoTo Oui
End If
Else: GoTo Check19
End If


Check19:
If FirstFour = "\2019" Then
FullPath = FLD(4) & fileNumber
StrFileExists = Dir(FullPath, vbDirectory)
If StrFileExists = "" Then
GoTo Check18
Else: GoTo Oui
End If
Else: GoTo Check18
End If


Check18:
If FirstFour = "\2018" Then
FullPath = FLD(5) & fileNumber
StrFileExists = Dir(FullPath, vbDirectory)
If StrFileExists = "" Then
GoTo CheckExtras
Else: GoTo Oui
End If
Else: GoTo CheckExtras
End If


CheckExtras:
'Check Deed Transfers
PrePath = "C:\Users\Meaghan Denelle\Dropbox\Denelle Law\Clients\2022 Deed Transfers"
FullPath = PrePath & FileNumberDirty
StrFileExists = Dir(FullPath, vbDirectory)
If StrFileExists = "" Then
GoTo CheckClients
Else
GoTo Oui
End If


'Check Regular Clients Folder
CheckClients:
PrePath = "C:\Users\Meaghan Denelle\Dropbox\Denelle Law\Clients"
FullPath = PrePath & fileNumberClient
StrFileExists = Dir(FullPath, vbDirectory)
If StrFileExists = "" Then
GoTo TryASuffix
Else
GoTo Oui
End If

CheckPrefix:
fileNumber = "\2022-" & ClientNameClean
GoTo Check22Terminal
Debug.Print fileNumber

Try2021Again:
fileNumber = "\2021-" & ClientNameClean
FullPath = FLD(2) & fileNumber
StrFileExists = Dir(FullPath, vbDirectory)
If StrFileExists = "" Then
fileNumber = "\" & ClientNameClean
GoTo Check21
Else
GoTo Oui
End If

Check22Terminal:
fileNumber = "\2022-" & ClientNameClean
FullPath = FLD(1) & fileNumber
StrFileExists = Dir(FullPath, vbDirectory)
If StrFileExists = "" Then
GoTo Check22ClosedTerminal
Else
GoTo Oui
End If

Check22ClosedTerminal:
FullPath = FLD(2) & fileNumber
StrFileExists = Dir(FullPath, vbDirectory)
If StrFileExists = "" Then
fileNumber = "\" & ClientNameClean
GoTo Try2021Again
Else
GoTo Oui
End If

'Use the shell to open the explorer window
Oui:
StrFileExists = Dir(FullPath, vbDirectory)
If StrFileExists = "" Then
MsgBox "Oui Error"
Else
Call Shell("explorer.exe " & """" & FullPath & """", vbNormalFocus)
GoTo TheEnd
End If

TheEndError:
MsgBox "Error" & fileNumber
GoTo TheEnd

TryASuffix:
fileNumber = "\2022-" & ClientNameClean & SFX(1)
FullPath = FLD(1) & fileNumber
StrFileExists = Dir(FullPath, vbDirectory)
If StrFileExists = "" Then
  FullPath = FLD(2) & fileNumber
  StrFileExists = Dir(FullPath, vbDirectory)
  Debug.Print StrFileExists
    If StrFileExists = "" Then
      fileNumber = "\2021-" & ClientNameClean & SFX(1)
      FullPath = FLD(2) & fileNumber
      StrFileExists = Dir(FullPath, vbDirectory)
        If StrFileExists = "" Then
            Debug.Print StrFileExists
          GoTo TryAsfx1
          Else
          GoTo Oui
        End If
      Else
      GoTo Oui
    End If
  Else
  GoTo Oui
End If

TryAsfx1:
fileNumber = "\2022-" & ClientNameClean & SFX(2)
FullPath = FLD(1) & fileNumber
StrFileExists = Dir(FullPath, vbDirectory)
If StrFileExists = "" Then
FullPath = FLD(2) & fileNumber
StrFileExists = Dir(FullPath, vbDirectory)
If StrFileExists = "" Then
fileNumber = "\2021-" & ClientNameClean & SFX(2)
FullPath = FLD(2) & fileNumber
StrFileExists = Dir(FullPath, vbDirectory)
If StrFileExists = "" Then
GoTo TryAsfx2
Else
GoTo Oui
End If
Else
GoTo Oui
End If
Else
GoTo Oui
End If

TryAsfx2:
fileNumber = "\2022-" & ClientNameClean & SFX(3)
FullPath = FLD(1) & fileNumber
StrFileExists = Dir(FullPath, vbDirectory)
If StrFileExists = "" Then
FullPath = FLD(2) & fileNumber
If StrFileExists = "" Then
fileNumber = "\2021-" & ClientNameClean & SFX(3)
FullPath = FLD(2) & fileNumber
StrFileExists = Dir(FullPath, vbDirectory)
If StrFileExists = "" Then
GoTo TryASuffix3
Else
GoTo Oui
End If
Else
GoTo Oui
End If
Else
GoTo Oui
End If

TryASuffix3:
fileNumber = "\2022-" & ClientNameClean & SFX(4)
FullPath = FLD(1) & fileNumber
StrFileExists = Dir(FullPath, vbDirectory)
If StrFileExists = "" Then
FullPath = FLD(2) & fileNumber
If StrFileExists = "" Then
fileNumber = "\2021-" & ClientNameClean & SFX(4)
FullPath = FLD(2) & fileNumber
StrFileExists = Dir(FullPath, vbDirectory)
If StrFileExists = "" Then
GoTo TryASuffix4
Else
GoTo Oui
End If
Else
GoTo Oui
End If
Else
GoTo Oui
End If

TryASuffix4:
fileNumber = "\2022-" & ClientNameClean & SFX(5)
FullPath = FLD(1) & fileNumber
StrFileExists = Dir(FullPath, vbDirectory)
If StrFileExists = "" Then
FullPath = FLD(2) & fileNumber
If StrFileExists = "" Then
fileNumber = "\2021-" & ClientNameClean & SFX(5)
FullPath = FLD(2) & fileNumber
StrFileExists = Dir(FullPath, vbDirectory)
If StrFileExists = "" Then
GoTo TryASuffix5
Else
GoTo Oui
End If
Else
GoTo Oui
End If
Else
GoTo Oui
End If

TryASuffix5:
fileNumber = "\2022-" & ClientNameClean & SFX(6)
FullPath = FLD(1) & fileNumber
StrFileExists = Dir(FullPath, vbDirectory)
If StrFileExists = "" Then
FullPath = FLD(2) & fileNumber
If StrFileExists = "" Then
fileNumber = "\2021-" & ClientNameClean & SFX(6)
FullPath = FLD(2) & fileNumber
StrFileExists = Dir(FullPath, vbDirectory)
If StrFileExists = "" Then
GoTo TryASuffix6
Else
GoTo Oui
End If
Else
GoTo Oui
End If
Else
GoTo Oui
End If

TryASuffix6:
fileNumber = "\2022-" & ClientNameClean & SFX(7)
FullPath = FLD(1) & fileNumber
StrFileExists = Dir(FullPath, vbDirectory)
If StrFileExists = "" Then
FullPath = FLD(2) & fileNumber
If StrFileExists = "" Then
fileNumber = "\2021-" & ClientNameClean & SFX(7)
FullPath = FLD(2) & fileNumber
StrFileExists = Dir(FullPath, vbDirectory)
If StrFileExists = "" Then
GoTo TryASuffix7
Else
GoTo Oui
End If
Else
GoTo Oui
End If
Else
GoTo Oui
End If

TryASuffix7:
fileNumber = "\2022-" & ClientNameClean & SFX(8)
FullPath = FLD(1) & fileNumber
StrFileExists = Dir(FullPath, vbDirectory)
If StrFileExists = "" Then
FullPath = FLD(2) & fileNumber
If StrFileExists = "" Then
fileNumber = "\2021-" & ClientNameClean & SFX(8)
FullPath = FLD(2) & fileNumber
StrFileExists = Dir(FullPath, vbDirectory)
If StrFileExists = "" Then
GoTo TryASuffix8
Else
GoTo Oui
End If
Else
GoTo Oui
End If
Else
GoTo Oui
End If

TryASuffix8:
fileNumber = "\2022-" & ClientNameClean & SFX(9)
FullPath = FLD(1) & fileNumber
StrFileExists = Dir(FullPath, vbDirectory)
If StrFileExists = "" Then
FullPath = FLD(2) & fileNumber
If StrFileExists = "" Then
fileNumber = "\2021-" & ClientNameClean & SFX(9)
FullPath = FLD(2) & fileNumber
StrFileExists = Dir(FullPath, vbDirectory)
If StrFileExists = "" Then
GoTo TryAsfx9
Else
GoTo Oui
End If
Else
GoTo Oui
End If
Else
GoTo Oui
End If

TryAsfx9:
fileNumber = "\2022-" & ClientNameClean & SFX(10)
FullPath = FLD(1) & fileNumber
StrFileExists = Dir(FullPath, vbDirectory)
If StrFileExists = "" Then
FullPath = FLD(2) & fileNumber
If StrFileExists = "" Then
fileNumber = "\2021-" & ClientNameClean & SFX(10)
FullPath = FLD(2) & fileNumber
StrFileExists = Dir(FullPath, vbDirectory)
If StrFileExists = "" Then
GoTo TryAsfx10
Else
GoTo Oui
End If
Else
GoTo Oui
End If
Else
GoTo Oui
End If

TryAsfx10:
fileNumber = "\2022-" & ClientNameClean & SFX(11)
FullPath = FLD(1) & fileNumber
StrFileExists = Dir(FullPath, vbDirectory)
If StrFileExists = "" Then
FullPath = FLD(2) & fileNumber
If StrFileExists = "" Then
fileNumber = "\2021-" & ClientNameClean & SFX(11)
FullPath = FLD(2) & fileNumber
StrFileExists = Dir(FullPath, vbDirectory)
If StrFileExists = "" Then
GoTo TheEndError
Else
GoTo Oui
End If
Else
GoTo Oui
End If
Else
GoTo Oui
End If

TheEnd:
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: This code is incredibly difficult to follow and desperately needs some indention/white space and rethinking the plethora of goto/label. That's the smoke, where your current problem is the fire. Where is it in here that you added the msgbox to check the directory path? And where is it that it's spitting out the wrong path? Can you add comments into the code to highlight those areas?

Comment: What values do you pass to the `Dir` function when it fails?

Comment: `SFX(6) = SFX(1) & SFX(0)` - FYI you never populate `SFX(0)`...

Comment: I *think* your code is using `fileNumber` before it's been assigned a value, but as noted already it's very difficult to follow the logic here.   You have arrays of paths and suffixes, but you're not looping over those using a For..Next approach, so your code is much larger than it should be, and also there's the `Goto` issue which means it can't just be read from top to bottom.

Comment: I'd love to change the many GoTos into a couple of For Loops but I can't figure out how. Do you have any suggestions on where I would start?

Answer (score 0):

Missing a `StrFileExists = Dir(FullPath, vbDirectory)` in `TryAsfx2:` to `TryAsfx10:`. Adding them didn't have an impact.

This is unraveled code, to process in a straightforward manner.

Labels have been commented out.

Some repetition has been removed with `Private Function folderExists(fullpath As String) As Boolean`.

```vb
Option Explicit ' Consider this mandatory
' Tools | Options | Editor tab
' Require Variable Declaration
' If desperate declare as Variant

Sub OpenMeUp()

'Prepare the searchable path
Dim ClientName As String
Dim ClientNameClean As String

Dim fileNumber As String
Dim fileNumberClient As String
Dim fileNumberDirty As String

Dim firstOne As String
Dim firstFour As String

Dim fullpath As String

Dim pos As Long
Dim pos2 As Long

'Name of the current folder
Dim myExplorer As explorer
Dim myFolder As folder

'On Error GoTo errorHandler  ' Not when developing/debugging

Set myExplorer = Application.ActiveExplorer
Set myFolder = myExplorer.currentFolder

' 1. Our office organizes client folders by
'     year, client number, and last name
'     (Ex. 2022-1234 Doe)

' 2. I organize my email inbox by
'     client number, last name and property address
'     (ex. 1234 Doe ---- 1 Main St.)

Debug.Print "myFolder: " & myFolder

'Set up folders array
Dim FLD(7) As Variant

FLD(1) = "R:"
FLD(2) = "W:"
FLD(3) = "O:"
FLD(4) = "R:\Archive\2019 Closings"
FLD(5) = "R:\Archive\2018 Closings"
FLD(6) = "C:\Users\Meaghan Denelle\Dropbox\Denelle Law\Clients\2022 Deed Transfers"
FLD(7) = "C:\Users\Meaghan Denelle\Dropbox\Denelle Law\Clients"

' For testing I created these folders
'FLD(1) = "C:\Users\userid\Test\" & "R"
'FLD(2) = "C:\Users\userid\Test\" & "W"
'FLD(3) = "C:\Users\userid\Test\" & "O"
'FLD(4) = "C:\Users\userid\Test\" & "R\Archive\2019 Closings"
'FLD(5) = "C:\Users\userid\Test\" & "R\Archive\2018 Closings"
'FLD(6) = "C:\Users\userid\Test\" & "C\Clients\2022 Deed Transfers"
'FLD(7) = "C:\Users\userid\Test\" & "C\Clients"

Dim i As Long
For i = LBound(FLD) To UBound(FLD)
    Debug.Print "FLD(" & i & "): " & FLD(i)
Next


Dim SFX(11) As Variant

SFX(1) = " (EF)"
SFX(2) = " Purchase"
SFX(3) = " Refi"
SFX(4) = " Commercial"
SFX(5) = " (CTD)"
SFX(6) = SFX(1) & SFX(0)
SFX(7) = SFX(3) & SFX(0)
SFX(8) = SFX(4) & SFX(0)
SFX(9) = SFX(3) & SFX(0)
SFX(10) = SFX(4) & SFX(1) & SFX(0)
SFX(11) = SFX(3) & SFX(5)

'For i = LBound(SFX) To UBound(SFX)
'    Debug.Print "SFX(" & i & "): " & SFX(i)
'Next


pos = InStr(myFolder.Name, "-")
'Debug.Print "pos: " & pos

pos2 = InStr(myFolder.Name, " ")
'Debug.Print "pos2: " & pos2

If (pos > 0) Then
    ClientName = Left(myFolder.Name, InStr(myFolder.Name, "-") - 1)
Else
    ClientName = Right(myFolder.Name, Len(myFolder.Name) - pos2)
End If
Debug.Print " ClientName......: " & ClientName

ClientNameClean = Replace(ClientName, " SR ", " Seller Rep")
Debug.Print " ClientNameClean.: " & ClientNameClean

fileNumberDirty = "\" & myFolder.Name
Debug.Print " FileNumberDirty.: " & fileNumberDirty

fileNumberClient = "\" & ClientName
Debug.Print " fileNumberClient: " & fileNumberClient

'This sorts the files based on their year prefix, if they have one.
'SortTheFiles:

firstOne = Left(ClientNameClean, 1)
Debug.Print
Debug.Print "firstOne.: " & firstOne

firstFour = Left(ClientNameClean, 4)
Debug.Print "firstFour: " & firstFour
 
If firstOne <> "1" Then

    'Check22:
    Debug.Print "Check22"
    If firstFour = "2022" Then
    
        'Check22Open:
        ' Drive R
        fileNumber = "\" & ClientNameClean
        Debug.Print " fileNumber: " & fileNumber
        fullpath = FLD(1) & fileNumber
        If folderExists(fullpath) = True Then callShell fullpath

        'Check22Closed:
        ' Drive W
        'Debug.Print " fileNumber not changed"
        Debug.Print " fileNumber: " & fileNumber
        fullpath = FLD(2) & fileNumber
        If folderExists(fullpath) = True Then callShell fullpath

    Else
        Debug.Print " firstFour <> 2022"
    
    End If
    
End If


'Check22Terminal:
Debug.Print "Check22Terminal"

' Drive R
fileNumber = "\2022-" & ClientNameClean
Debug.Print " fileNumber: " & fileNumber
fullpath = FLD(1) & fileNumber
If folderExists(fullpath) = True Then callShell fullpath


'Check22ClosedTerminal:
Debug.Print "Check22ClosedTerminal"
' Drive W
'Debug.Print " fileNumber not changed"
Debug.Print " fileNumber: " & fileNumber
fullpath = FLD(2) & fileNumber
If folderExists(fullpath) = True Then callShell fullpath


'Try2021Again:
Debug.Print "Try2021Again"
' Drive W
fileNumber = "\2021-" & ClientNameClean
Debug.Print " fileNumber: " & fileNumber
fullpath = FLD(2) & fileNumber
If folderExists(fullpath) = True Then callShell fullpath


'Check21:
Debug.Print "Check21:"
' Drive W
fileNumber = "\" & ClientNameClean
Debug.Print " fileNumber: " & fileNumber

'If FirstFour = "\2021" Then
Debug.Print "  FirstFour: " & firstFour
If firstFour = "2021" Then
    fullpath = FLD(2) & fileNumber
    If folderExists(fullpath) = True Then callShell fullpath

Else
    Debug.Print "   firstFour <> 2021"
    Debug.Print "   folderExists bypassed."
    
End If


'Check20:
Debug.Print "Check20:"
' Drive O
'Debug.Print " fileNumber not changed"
Debug.Print " fileNumber: " & fileNumber
Debug.Print "  FirstFour: " & firstFour

'If FirstFour = "\2020" Then
If firstFour = "2020" Then
    fullpath = FLD(3) & fileNumber
    If folderExists(fullpath) = True Then callShell fullpath
        
Else
    Debug.Print "   firstFour <> 2020"
    Debug.Print "   folderExists bypassed."
    
End If


'Check19:
Debug.Print "Check19:"

' Folder R:\Archive\2019 Closings
'Debug.Print " fileNumber not changed"
Debug.Print " fileNumber: " & fileNumber

Debug.Print "  FirstFour: " & firstFour
'If FirstFour = "\2019" Then
If firstFour = "2019" Then
    fullpath = FLD(4) & fileNumber
    If folderExists(fullpath) = True Then callShell fullpath
        
Else
    Debug.Print "   firstFour <> 2019"
    Debug.Print "   folderExists bypassed."
    
End If


'Check18:
Debug.Print "Check18:"
' Folder R:\Archive\2018 Closings
'Debug.Print " fileNumber not changed"
Debug.Print " fileNumber: " & fileNumber
    
Debug.Print "  FirstFour: " & firstFour
'If FirstFour = "\2018" Then
If firstFour = "2018" Then
    fullpath = FLD(5) & fileNumber
    If folderExists(fullpath) = True Then callShell fullpath
        
Else
    Debug.Print "   firstFour <> 2018"
    Debug.Print "   folderExists bypassed."
    
End If


'Check Deed Transfers
'CheckExtras:
Debug.Print "CheckExtras:"
' C:\Users\Meaghan Denelle\Dropbox\Denelle Law\Clients\2022 Deed Transfers
fileNumber = fileNumberDirty
Debug.Print " fileNumber: " & fileNumber
    
fullpath = FLD(6) & fileNumber
If folderExists(fullpath) = True Then callShell fullpath


'Check Regular Clients Folder
'CheckClients:
Debug.Print "CheckClients:"
    
' C:\Users\Meaghan Denelle\Dropbox\Denelle Law\Clients
fileNumber = fileNumberClient
Debug.Print " fileNumber: " & fileNumber
fullpath = FLD(7) & fileNumber
If folderExists(fullpath) = True Then callShell fullpath
    
    
'TryASuffix:
Debug.Print "TryASuffix:"

' Drive R:
fileNumber = "\2022-" & ClientNameClean & SFX(1)
Debug.Print " fileNumber: " & fileNumber
fullpath = FLD(1) & fileNumber
If folderExists(fullpath) = True Then callShell fullpath

' Drive W
'Debug.Print " fileNumber not changed"
Debug.Print " fileNumber: " & fileNumber
fullpath = FLD(2) & fileNumber
If folderExists(fullpath) = True Then callShell fullpath

' Drive W
fileNumber = "\2021-" & ClientNameClean & SFX(1)
Debug.Print " fileNumber: " & fileNumber
fullpath = FLD(2) & fileNumber
If folderExists(fullpath) = True Then callShell fullpath


'TryAsfx1:
Debug.Print "TryAsfx1:"

' Drive R
fileNumber = "\2022-" & ClientNameClean & SFX(2)
Debug.Print " fileNumber: " & fileNumber
fullpath = FLD(1) & fileNumber
If folderExists(fullpath) = True Then callShell fullpath

' Drive W
'Debug.Print " fileNumber not changed"
Debug.Print " fileNumber: " & fileNumber
fullpath = FLD(2) & fileNumber
If folderExists(fullpath) = True Then callShell fullpath
    
' Drive W
fileNumber = "\2021-" & ClientNameClean & SFX(2)
Debug.Print " fileNumber: " & fileNumber
fullpath = FLD(2) & fileNumber
If folderExists(fullpath) = True Then callShell fullpath


'TryAsfx2:
Debug.Print "TryAsfx2:"

' Drive R
fileNumber = "\2022-" & ClientNameClean & SFX(3)
Debug.Print " fileNumber: " & fileNumber
fullpath = FLD(1) & fileNumber
If folderExists(fullpath) = True Then callShell fullpath

' Drive W
'Debug.Print " fileNumber not changed"
Debug.Print " fileNumber: " & fileNumber
fullpath = FLD(2) & fileNumber
If folderExists(fullpath) = True Then callShell fullpath

' Drive W
fileNumber = "\2021-" & ClientNameClean & SFX(3)
Debug.Print " fileNumber: " & fileNumber
fullpath = FLD(2) & fileNumber
If folderExists(fullpath) = True Then callShell fullpath


'TryASuffix3:
Debug.Print "TryASuffix3:"

' Drive R
fileNumber = "\2022-" & ClientNameClean & SFX(4)
Debug.Print " fileNumber: " & fileNumber
fullpath = FLD(1) & fileNumber
If folderExists(fullpath) = True Then callShell fullpath
    
' Drive W
'Debug.Print " fileNumber not changed"
Debug.Print " fileNumber: " & fileNumber
fullpath = FLD(2) & fileNumber
If folderExists(fullpath) = True Then callShell fullpath
    
' Drive W
fileNumber = "\2021-" & ClientNameClean & SFX(4)
Debug.Print " fileNumber: " & fileNumber
fullpath = FLD(2) & fileNumber
If folderExists(fullpath) = True Then callShell fullpath
    

'TryASuffix4:
Debug.Print "TryASuffix4:"

' Drive R
fileNumber = "\2022-" & ClientNameClean & SFX(5)
Debug.Print " fileNumber: " & fileNumber
fullpath = FLD(1) & fileNumber
If folderExists(fullpath) = True Then callShell fullpath

' Drive W
'Debug.Print " fileNumber not changed"
Debug.Print " fileNumber: " & fileNumber
fullpath = FLD(2) & fileNumber
If folderExists(fullpath) = True Then callShell fullpath

' Drive W
fileNumber = "\2021-" & ClientNameClean & SFX(5)
Debug.Print " fileNumber: " & fileNumber
fullpath = FLD(2) & fileNumber
If folderExists(fullpath) = True Then callShell fullpath


'TryASuffix5:
Debug.Print "TryASuffix5:"

' Drive R
fileNumber = "\2022-" & ClientNameClean & SFX(6)
Debug.Print " fileNumber: " & fileNumber
fullpath = FLD(1) & fileNumber
If folderExists(fullpath) = True Then callShell fullpath

' Drive W
'Debug.Print " fileNumber not changed"
Debug.Print " fileNumber: " & fileNumber
fullpath = FLD(2) & fileNumber
If folderExists(fullpath) = True Then callShell fullpath
    
' Drive W
fileNumber = "\2021-" & ClientNameClean & SFX(6)
Debug.Print " fileNumber: " & fileNumber
fullpath = FLD(2) & fileNumber
If folderExists(fullpath) = True Then callShell fullpath


'TryASuffix6:
Debug.Print "TryASuffix6:"

' Drive R
fileNumber = "\2022-" & ClientNameClean & SFX(7)
Debug.Print " fileNumber: " & fileNumber
fullpath = FLD(1) & fileNumber
If folderExists(fullpath) = True Then callShell fullpath
    
' Drive W
'Debug.Print " fileNumber not changed"
Debug.Print " fileNumber: " & fileNumber
fullpath = FLD(2) & fileNumber
If folderExists(fullpath) = True Then callShell fullpath
    
' Drive W
fileNumber = "\2021-" & ClientNameClean & SFX(7)
Debug.Print " fileNumber: " & fileNumber
fullpath = FLD(2) & fileNumber
If folderExists(fullpath) = True Then callShell fullpath
    

'TryASuffix7:
Debug.Print "TryASuffix7:"

' Drive R
fileNumber = "\2022-" & ClientNameClean & SFX(8)
Debug.Print " fileNumber: " & fileNumber
fullpath = FLD(1) & fileNumber
If folderExists(fullpath) = True Then callShell fullpath

' Drive W
'Debug.Print " fileNumber not changed"
Debug.Print " fileNumber: " & fileNumber
fullpath = FLD(2) & fileNumber
If folderExists(fullpath) = True Then callShell fullpath
    
' Drive W
fileNumber = "\2021-" & ClientNameClean & SFX(8)
Debug.Print " fileNumber: " & fileNumber
fullpath = FLD(2) & fileNumber
If folderExists(fullpath) = True Then callShell fullpath
    

'TryASuffix8:
Debug.Print "TryASuffix8:"

' Drive R
fileNumber = "\2022-" & ClientNameClean & SFX(9)
Debug.Print " fileNumber: " & fileNumber
fullpath = FLD(1) & fileNumber
If folderExists(fullpath) = True Then callShell fullpath
    
' Drive W
'Debug.Print " fileNumber not changed"
Debug.Print " fileNumber: " & fileNumber
fullpath = FLD(2) & fileNumber
If folderExists(fullpath) = True Then callShell fullpath

' Drive W
fileNumber = "\2021-" & ClientNameClean & SFX(9)
Debug.Print " fileNumber: " & fileNumber
fullpath = FLD(2) & fileNumber
If folderExists(fullpath) = True Then callShell fullpath


'TryAsfx9:
Debug.Print "TryAsfx9:"

' Drive R
fileNumber = "\2022-" & ClientNameClean & SFX(10)
Debug.Print " fileNumber: " & fileNumber
fullpath = FLD(1) & fileNumber
If folderExists(fullpath) = True Then callShell fullpath

' Drive W
'Debug.Print " fileNumber not changed"
Debug.Print " fileNumber: " & fileNumber
fullpath = FLD(2) & fileNumber
If folderExists(fullpath) = True Then callShell fullpath

' Drive W
fileNumber = "\2021-" & ClientNameClean & SFX(10)
Debug.Print " fileNumber: " & fileNumber
fullpath = FLD(2) & fileNumber
If folderExists(fullpath) = True Then callShell fullpath


'TryAsfx10:
Debug.Print "TryAsfx10:"

' Drive R
fileNumber = "\2022-" & ClientNameClean & SFX(11)
Debug.Print " fileNumber: " & fileNumber
fullpath = FLD(1) & fileNumber
If folderExists(fullpath) = True Then callShell fullpath

' Drive W
'Debug.Print " fileNumber not changed"
Debug.Print " fileNumber: " & fileNumber
fullpath = FLD(2) & fileNumber
If folderExists(fullpath) = True Then callShell fullpath

' Drive W
fileNumber = "\2021-" & ClientNameClean & SFX(11)
Debug.Print " fileNumber: " & fileNumber
fullpath = FLD(2) & fileNumber
If folderExists(fullpath) = True Then callShell fullpath

MsgBox "Folder not found."

Exit Sub

errorHandler:
    MsgBox "Error number: " & Err.numBer & vbCr & vbCr & "Error description: " & Err.Description
    
End Sub


Private Function folderExists(fullpath As String) As Boolean
    Debug.Print "   FullPath: " & fullpath
    If dir(fullpath, vbDirectory) = "" Then
        'Debug.Print "   Folder does not exist."
        folderExists = False
    Else
        folderExists = True
    End If
End Function


Private Function callShell(fullpath As String) As Boolean
    Shell "explorer.exe " & """" & fullpath & """", vbNormalFocus
    End
End Function
```